# LibreOffice Doc to PDF Security

Tags: security, libreoffice

I am building a simple app that you send an email to a specific address and it converts the email attachments to PDF using LibreOffice.

I don't know much about security but how can I prevent people from sending a virus as a .doc or any other attachment to our service and thus installing the virus on our server when the file is opened?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to know a lot about security.

Certainly, its unlikely that malware would survive the conversion process, but you need to protect your service. Libreoffice is [not immune](https://www.libreoffice.org/about-us/security/advisories/) from vulnerabilities. But its default handling of macros is a lot more robust than other office applications. Also, it is usually fast in releasing updates. Hence your best protection is choosing a platform which has a fast turnaround on releasing fixes with automatic installation; ubuntu, fedora and opensuse are obvious candidates.

(But I wonder about your service model when exporting a pdf directly from libreoffice is so easy).

Comment: I'm trying to learn as much as possible - it is a bottomless pit though!

My main concern would be for someone's email to be compromised and someone sends a virus ending with .doc that isn't actually a word doc but a virus. Our script would open the file anyway which is the issue. 

The service model is more than just saving an email as a pdf, it is just one aspect of it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you use an email host that checks for viruses by default. And if LibreOffice is anything like MS Office, you can set it to block any macros in the document.
But I would bet the the conversion process doesn't even touch macros, you should be safe.

Comment: Libreoffice is nothing like msoffice. AV is a very poor first line of defence.